# CSS Navigation Rounding off the Last Child

Tags: css, html-lists, nav, css-selectors

Ok so heres whats weird. The last child in my horizontal nav has rounded edges. Using the
nav ul li:last-child a:hover, I was able to get the last child's hover state to also have rounded edges. However, it is a drop down. When I move down to its submenu, the parent child LOSES its rounded edges AND the children of this submenu now have the rounded edges (and they are not supposed to).

Take a look to see what I'm talking about.

```
nav ul li:last-child, nav ul li:last-child a:hover {
    border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Try on jsFiddle

Hover over VIP Travel

http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/5/)***

Hi now replace to this

```
    nav ul li:last-child, nav ul li:last-child a:hover{
// here style 
}
```

**into this**

```
    nav ul li:last-child, nav ul li:last-child a{
//  here style 
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/5/)***

### ----------------------

***[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/6/)*** I think u want this

### -----------

### -----------

***[Updated-of-Drop-Down](http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/10/)*** of **drop down styling**

**Just add This if your requirement**

```
nav ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul > li > ul li a {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul > li > ul > li a:hover{
border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. One more thing though....you will see on Travel Deals, the submenu items' hover state has the right side rounded too. How can I straighten them?

Comment: HI @swg1cor14 now define this css for last submenu anchor hover nav ul > li > ul > li a:hover{
border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
}                Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/9/

Comment: Hello @swg1cor14 I have updated my Answer i think u want this one demo http://jsfiddle.net/XBUzw/10/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a more specific rule, e.g. use the child selector instead of descendant.

```
nav > ul > li:last-child, nav > ul > li:last-child > a:hover {
    border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/XBUzw/3/

Comment: what the f**k default color is white ... i thought fiddle is not working ...lol

Comment: @NullPointer It got me too xD